# Google Maps infowindow doesn't open / display:none

Tags: jquery, google-maps, drupal, google-maps-markers

I'm currently working on a store locator for a grocery store. Their website was built in Drupal, but I'm coding the store locator from scratch rather than using Drupal modules.

So far, everything seems to come together nicely, but I can't figure out why my info windows are not showing when someone clicks a marker. After doing some research and trying out different things, the code below seems to be somewhat responding:
when clicking on a marker, the map re-centers itself to make room for the bubble, but the bubble never shows.

**Update:**

After some more testing I found that the bubbles are indeed created. The markup is there, but for some reason google adds a **display:none** inline style to its container on click. Now I'm wondering how I can prevent this?

Any ideas/help is greatly appreciated.

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.storelocator = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {        

        var map;
        var markers_array = [];

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
            var mapOptions = {
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.030, -73.411),
                  zoom: 10,
                  maxZoom: 16,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            $.get('/storelocator/storexml', function(xml) {                         
                $(xml).find('marker').each(function() {
                    var banner_name = $(this).attr('name');
                    var address = $(this).attr('address');
                    var distance = parseFloat($(this).attr('distance'));
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('lat')), parseFloat($(this).attr('lng')));

                    createMarker(map, latlng, banner_name, address);
                    bounds.extend(latlng);
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });
            });
    });



        function createMarker(map, latlng, banner_name, address) {

            var icon_image = {
                url: '/sites/default/modules/storelocator/images/' + banner_name + '.png',
                size: new google.maps.Size(25, 30),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 30)
            }
            var icon_shadow = {
                url: '/sites/default/modules/storelocator/images/shadow.png',
                size: new google.maps.Size(40, 30),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 30)
            }
            var clickable_area = {
                coord: [1, 1, 1, 30, 25, 30, 30, 1],
                type: 'poly'
            }
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: latlng,
                shadow: icon_shadow,
                icon: icon_image,
                shape: clickable_area,
                title: address,
                html: '<strong>' + banner_name + '</strong><br/>' + address
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(this.html);
                infoWindow.open(map, this); 
            });

            markers_array.push(marker);
        }

    }
};
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Where is your Marker? where is the bubble window? I can't see it here??

Comment: What javascript errors do you get?  Can you provide a jsfiddle or a link to a map that exhibits the problem?

Comment: no javascript errors at all. I can't provide a link since the project is behind a VPN.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:
[Google maps InfoWindow not opening on click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933050/google-maps-infowindow-not-opening-on-click-event#answer-4943492)

Seems like your problem could have the same cause although I'm not sure what it is. So as in the linked answer, try this:

```
function addInfoWindow(marker, content) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a hopefully good guess here, but I would say to definitely move your definition of infoWindow to be outside of the createMarker function, as with each call to createMarker you are actually redefining infoWindow and will definitely lose scope with previously created markers.

edit: Another option would be to actually assign the infoWindow to the marker it's self, eg: marker.infoWindow = etc. etc., marker.infoWindow.setContent(etc. etc. but I would say that's likely unnecessary, as the first option I gave you is best practice generally

Comment: Moving the definition of infoWindow outside of createMarker doesn't change any of the behavior. Alerting the content on click works, but something is hiding the bubble on open. Assigning infoWindow to the marker itself stops the map from reacting at all.

Comment: Well, ok, was a quick guess, but I still stand by saying not to redefine infoWindow all the time. Only other things, have you verified that '/sites/default/modules/storelocator/images/' + banner_name + '.png' is actually in fact correct and accessible in browser? Otherwise, what happens if you try default markers without the custom icon, shadow & shape? Does it work then?

Comment: never mind, was thinking about the marker icons, not the infoWindow which I wouldn't think the marker icons should affect negatively