# Google Map infowindow not opening

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using Google Maps in my Rails app and I face some difficulties.
I want to show an infowindow when a user clicks on a circle. It works fine when he clicks on a marker but now that I have circles it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
  markers_json = <%= raw @circles %>;
  var map;
  var infoWindow;

  buildMap = function(){
    var mapStyle = [
      // https://snazzymaps.com/style/70/unsaturated-browns
      {"elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#ff4400"},{"saturation":-68},{"lightness":-4},{"gamma":0.72}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.icon"},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#0077ff"},{"gamma":3.1}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"hue":"#00ccff"},{"gamma":0.44},{"saturation":-33}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","stylers":[{"hue":"#44ff00"},{"saturation":-23}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"hue":"#007fff"},{"gamma":0.77},{"saturation":65},{"lightness":99}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"gamma":0.11},{"weight":5.6},{"saturation":99},{"hue":"#0091ff"},{"lightness":-86}]},{"featureType":"transit.line","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":-48},{"hue":"#ff5e00"},{"gamma":1.2},{"saturation":-23}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"saturation":-64},{"hue":"#ff9100"},{"lightness":16},{"gamma":0.47},{"weight":2.7}]}
    ];

    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    map = handler.buildMap({
      internal: {id: 'map'},
      provider: {
        //disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: mapStyle,
        scrollwheel: false
      }
    }, function(){
      var circles = handler.addCircles(markers_json, {strokeWeight: 1, strokeColor: '#aaa'});
      handler.bounds.extendWith(circles);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();

      for (var i = 0; i <  circles.length; ++i) {
        var marker = circles[i];
        //google.maps.event.addListener(marker.serviceObject, 'click', onMarkerClick(marker));
        addInfoWindow(marker, 'hey');
      }

    });

  };

  function addInfoWindow(marker, content) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker.serviceObject, 'click', function () {
      i = infoWindow.open(map, marker.serviceObject);
      console.log(i);
    });
  }
```

I have this error again and again when I try to open the infowindow: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined(…)`

So I tried doing `i = infoWindow.open(map.serviceObject, marker.serviceObject);`
but now nothing happens, I even don't have an error message.

I really don't know what else I can do... Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 2nd argument of `infoWindow.open();` has to be an MVC-Object with a `position`-property of type `google.maps.LatLng`

A `google.maps.Marker` does have a `position`-property, but a `google.maps.Circle` doesn't.

Use `setOptions` to set `map` and `position`(e.g. center of the circle) of the infowindow:

```
infoWindow.setOptions({
  map:      map.serviceObject, 
  position: marker.serviceObject.getCenter()
});
```